# Can Salesforce Radar Chart have less than 10 values on yAxis

Tags: visualforce-charting

I am using the below code to plot radar chart and I only want values 1through 5 on yAxis. However the values are duplicated as shown below. I tried using margins property, but that did not make any difference. Is there any way of restricting the axis to less than 10 or hiding the yaxis labels, so that its not confusing?

[image]

```
    <apex:chart name="myChart" height="600" width="650" legend="false" data="{!data}">
         <apex:axis type="Radial" position="radial" minimum="0" maximum="5"  />
         <apex:radarSeries title="XXXX" xField="field" yField="value" tips="true" opacity="0.4"/>
    </apex:chart>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, looks like this if not possible for current Winter 18 release.

Setting of `grid` or `gridFill` properties of `axis` doesn't help, and if we set `rendered` attribute to `false` then the whole radial chart will disappear.

You might consider posting an idea on [Idea Exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) and if you persuade 250 users to vote for it, Salesforce may consider and implement such feature in the future release.